# In SystemVerilog how do I use a parameter to instantiate multiple signals and registers?

Tags: system-verilog

I creating a module that gets passed a parameter N.
N will be used to create N-2 signals, with the 1st signal having a width of 1, the next signal has width 2, up to the N-1 signal having width N-1. I've tried: (which didn't seem to work)

```
for (genvar num = 2;num < N;num++) begin
  logic [num-2:0] signal[num];
end
```

I think I can (although I'm not sure how to) use a generate to create N-2 register elements, but I don't think generates are legal in type definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say something doesnt work, you need to explain what went wrong. You probably had a problem because you did not name your generate block

```
for (genvar num = 2;num < N;num++) begin : NN
  logic [num-2:0] signal;
end
```

This creates

```
NN[2].signal   // 1 bit
NN[3].signal   // 2 bits
...
NN[N-1].signal // N-1 bits
```

Note that you cannot reference `NN[i]` where `i` is a variable; it must be a constant or another genvar.